# formula to plot ( 1/4 eliptical) curve with only minx,miny and maxx,maxy

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

Here is the curve i wish to plot with a function:

[image: eliptical curve]

I expect the curve to be 1/4 of an elipse but I only have the coordinates to work with (minx,miny and maxx,maxy). I've been using the graphing tool at: http://itools.subhashbose.com/grapher  but I haven't been able to remember way back to highschool when we worked on functions like these (it's been over 30 years). Any help greatly appreciated.

Note: answers come in quick, wish i had specified earlier the format of the equation ideally looks like: `f(x) = ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define $a=x_{max}-x_{min}$
and $b=y_{max}-y_{min}$

then you need to plot ...

$$ y=y_{max} - b\sqrt{1-\frac{(x-x_{min})^2}{a^2}   }   $$

from $x=x_{min}$ to $x=x_{max}$

Comment: could your equation above also be expressed like:

```f(x) = Ymax - ( Ymax - Ymin ) * sqrt( 1 - ( pow( X - Xmin, 2 ) / pow( Xmax - Xmin, 2 ) ) )```

Comment: just tested it (using the translation of your formula) and it looks correct in all ways except that I have a half-ellipse (not quarter ellipse) - I may translated it wrong: https://bit.ly/2XHFb2Y

Comment: Grapher is definitely not the best graphing tool on the internet, it does not support peicewise functions, GeoGebra is probably the best graphing tool on the internet , check out the graph I made with adjustable max and min https://www.geogebra.org/classic/yuzrfs7y

Comment: holy smokes, you nailed it in the comments :) I'm going to check this answer just for the comment alone - tremendously helpful

Answer (score 0):

If we let $$a=X_{max}-X_{min};\, b=Y_{max}-Y_{min};$$

then parametrically we can plot

$$ X= X_{min}+ a \cos t, Y= Y_{max} + b \sin t $$